# Is there such a thing as a non-injective flasque abelian sheaf?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra

It's well-known (and fairly easy to prove) that over any topological space $X$, if a sheaf $\mathcal{F}\in\mathfrak{Ab}(X)$ is injective, then it must also be flasque. However, I've never seen mentioned that this is an equivalence, so I suspect there must be some example of a sheaf $\mathcal{F}\in\mathfrak{Ab}(X)$ that is flasque without being injective. However, it's relatively difficult to prove that a sheaf is injective, so I don't see how to construct such an example.

Comment: Is a (non-zero) constant sheaf on e.g. the algebraic variety P^1 flasque but not injective? Oh -- and when you make canonical flasque resolutions you get sheaves like the product of loads of skyscraper sheaves, one for each point. Those are flasque. Wait -- isn't a skyscraper sheaf flasque? Anyway, there are some ideas. Maybe that's an answer actually.

Comment: +1 for showing "thought in action"!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just take a non-injective abelian group and a point in your space, and form the skyscraper sheaf at that point with stalk the abelian group.